# which questions falls under the tag 'problem-solving'?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-wikis

I am not sure how to use this [problem-solving](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-solving) tag, since by name it seems to me that any problem/excercise would fall under this category?!

Comment: I *think* (not having used the tag myself, but having seen it used) that the tag is for questions that actually concerns the "art and technique of problem solving".

Comment: Usually I would use this tag for something which resembles a Putnam or Olympiad question.

Answer (score 5):

I think the "problem solving" tag should be for questions about problem solving *in general*. For example, "what are the best strategies for solving inequalities?". It should not be used for concrete questions that simply *use* problem solving techniques, if those concrete questions are not *about* problem solving techniques. So I would say "problem solving" tag is for meta discussion about problem solving itself, not for questions that merely want to apply problem solving techniques. Otherwise, as the question here says, every single question could be tagged as "problem solving".

I think similar things about the "proof strategy" and "proof writing" tags. These should not be used on questions solely because the answer is a proof - they should be reserved for questions *about* proof strategies and proof writing.

Comment: From the viewpoint of this interpretation the tag has been [grossly misused](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-solving) -- very few questions tagged in this way are about strategies for problem solving.

Comment: Yes, I have the sense that these tags are very heavily misused, but the software makes it inconvenient to go through and fix them because it would require bumping all the questions. I try to remove the tags from questions that I answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be: <strike>this is a meta-tag that indicates contest-type problems that are normally associated with [AoPS](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/index.php).</strike> this is a tag for the questions about problem-solving strategies in general.

The AoPS style questions can be marked with "contest-math". It's not clear to me whether contest-math should be used as a standalone tag, or in conjunction with subject tags.

Sub-question 1: should the tag be applied to questions like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195764/inequality-a7b2b7c2c7a2-leq-3#195764) when the OP does not do it? Such problems have some distinguishing features (i.e., nothing is expected in terms of "motivation"), so having a clear label could be helpful to voters.

Sub-question 2: is the set of AoPS-suitable problems a subset of the set of MSE-suitable problems? My guess is that the answer is yes.

Comment: No, I don't think the thing linked in sub-question 1 should have the "problem solving" tag, because it is not about problem solving in general.

Comment: Perhaps the [tag:contest-math] is closer to AoPS-type questions?

Comment: The "content-math" tag looks good to me for problems that have appeared in math contests.

Comment: I don't think this should be defined in terms of AoPS, as though everyone uses that site, or knows what it is, or agrees what the features of AoPS material are.   Can "AoPS suitable" be defined without reference to AoPS? Concepts like olympiad math, (contest-math) tag, Putnam problems, journal problems, and puzzles are familiar enough.